# Best approach for Synchronization Mysql databases using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, synchronization

I have a requirement as below.

- Windows application in c# with My sql database.
- MySql database in both local and server .
- One centralized server with many client
- Synchronizing the server database at each time when the new entry or update is
  happen in local machine.
- The server data also needs to be updated in local at regular intervals inorder to avoid conflicts

I need to know what is the best approach to follow to make this synchronization without any conflicts.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like you want a MySQL replication solution; if so, this should be asked on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: Not a good question for SO - search for possible solutions and come back with questions on implementation details. The topic itself is popular enough by itself but much broader that SO questions are expected to be. Also "best approach" is very subjective thing and essentially asking for discussion on different implementations... I.e. I'd consider paying someone to implement it a best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your "local machines" are always connected to the server, you don't need a local database - you can connect directly to the server as one MySQL server can handle multiple clients...

If, however, your central server is not always available or your clients can go offline and should still be able to work and they synchronize data when they come back online, then what you need to build is an [Occasionally Connected Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384572.aspx).

See if you can use any of the recommendations on that page. If I were you, I would start exploring [Synchronization Services for ADO.NET](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16515) (MySQL has a [full ADO.NET provider](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/))

Comment: Thanks for the info.I also need to consider if there is any connectivity issue,there might be conflict in data.I have an idea to update the data from client to server in scheduled time intervals.